# Jmeter how to get end time for a request?

Tags: jmeter

I have added a listener to get the summary of my requests. The summary report gives me the start time of request. But, how can I add the time request was completed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a listener, the [listeners don't add any value, they just consume resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/), all the data you need can be found in [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

For example when you run your JMeter test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/result.csv
```

the first 2 columns are:

1. `timeStamp` - sample start time in milliseconds from the beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
2. `elapsed` - sample execution time, in milliseconds as well

So you can get the "end time" by summing `timeStamp` and `elapsed`

[image]